# Power method for complex Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

How should the power iteration be modified to handle complex yet Hermitian matrices? Because the matrix is Hermitian, the eigenvalues are real. I realize that the power method will fail if the eigenvalues are non-real, but I would think that it should work in my case.

It seems to me that the naive algorithm should be unchanged. There is a possible complication when doing the scaled power iteration, where one computes the norm of the current iterate.

There is also a potential issue with deflation for computing multiple eigenpairs. Does the simple Hotelling deflation method not work for complex Hermitians?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two simple changes that need to be made.

First, in the power iteration itself, the full complex version of the Rayleigh quotient $R(M, x) = x^H M x / (x^H x)$ must be used, instead of its simplified real version $x^T M x / (x^T x)$. Thus, the algorithm would be:
$$
\begin{align}
\textrm{while not converged}: & \\
w \leftarrow& A v \\
v \leftarrow& w / \|w\|_2 \\
\lambda \leftarrow& v^H A v
\end{align}
$$
(See [this PR to TheAlgorithms](https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Python/pull/5925)  to see Python code for this change.)

In addition, deflation for computing multiple eigenvalues/eigenvectors must also account for the fact that the eigenvector may be complex. For example, Hotelling deflation would now be

$$
A \leftarrow A - \lambda v v^H / (v^H v).
$$